# Why is disabling E_WARNING in PHP considered bad practice?

Tags: php, security, conventions, suppress-warnings

From what I understand, at least with PHP v7.3, this is the "best practice" PHP [error_reporting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) value for a *Production* system:

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED);
```

I notice that this reports `E_WARNING`.

I am interested in the down-sides of ignoring warnings, e.g.:

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_WARNING);
```

This pushes warnings under the rug, which will be bad for the code quality in your project in the long run. So far, it's obvious that ignoring warnings is a bad practice.

However, lets add another factor into the mix. It is common to configure a custom PHP error handler to halt the appliction if a *reported* error is raised. For example, the Yii1 [handleError](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CApplication#handleError-detail) function terminates the application. I imagine many PHP frameworks take the same approach. This actually causes some confusion because the [php docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php) say:

> E_WARNING Run-time warnings (non-fatal errors). Execution of the script is **not halted**.

But (at least in Yii1), execution of the script would be halted if `E_WARNING` was included in the [error_reporting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) value (due to the yii custom error handler).

In my current project `E_WARNING` is reported on test systems, but not currently in Production, and it's going to take maybe 80 hours to fix all the warnings so that we can enable it and follow best practices. I think it's worth the effort and I'm going to propose it to the team, but I need to come to the table with some benefits to the project, otherwise the ROI will be deemed too low. I only have 2 benefits so far:

1. It would be best for code quality, longer term.
2. It could be a security issue not to halt if a warning occurs. One example I can think of is that the warning might be about an invalid regexp (invalid regexps have been known to be vulnerable in the past). Sometimes user input is used in the regexp and this opens up attack vectors for sure.

Can you think of any other reasons?

---

*To sum up my question (the TL;DR)*:

What is the danger of not halting the application if a `E_WARNING` occurs?

Comment: To be honest, I just read the TLDR. But you shouldn't suppress warnings, you should handle them instead. Meaning, you should account for something going wrong with the input/the data, and act accordingly. Suppressing errors can lead to code being run without the appropriate data, which can cause problems further down the pipeline. More "defensive" code is often better for the end-user (they get a message on what they did wrong), and it ensures that code only runs with the appropriate data.

Comment: E_WARNING will not break the behaviour of the application. That's why, it is only useful on dev environment. No one want to display an unhandled warning message for enduser.

Answer (score 2):

You should treat all warnings as errors. Basically, warnings are errors that do not stop the execution of your script. In this case they could be deemed to be more dangerous than errors. You generally don't want the application to keep on executing if the preceding actions failed. This could be disastrous for a badly coded program.

Warnings tell you that the code has serious problems and not that your code isn't following best practices.

There's a plan to increase the severity of all errors in the future release of PHP. See https://wiki.php.net/rfc/engine_warnings

If you can afford to ignore all the warnings and your code still executes correctly it is a sign of a serious code smell. All warnings should be logged and fixed as soon as possible. They should be treated not as potential bugs, but as existing bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally your team should fix all causes of warnings before your software goes to production (testing and QA), after all a hidden problem is still a problem. There's a nice quick read about errors [here](https://phptherightway.com/#errors_and_exceptions).